# How to attack defending balloons?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was attacking an enemy base and in their Clan Castle they had Balloons. My barbarians got their ass kicked. How can you attack the balloons in battle?

Comment: Use air based troops like minions that balloons can't defend against. If you don't have access to these, lure the loons to a corner and make a circle of archers (at least 10) around the loons. Alternatively you can clump the loons and place couple of wizards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat balloons like any melee troops with a splash attack, except they fly.  So, lure them into a corner and then hit them with spread out archers, minions, or wizards (most common units that can hit air).

- Archers are cheap but will take them down slowly, which gives them a chance to fly over a group and take them out on death.
- Minions I believe will not die from the bombs dropped upon death, so you can take out an entire castle full of balloons with a couple if you can spare the time.
- Wizards will take them all down at once if they're clumped together and minimize how much damage they do on death.

Comment: OK I only ave archers so far so I'll use those.

Comment: Minions fly and can attack flying troops. The bombs will only affect ground troops over an area, not air troops.

Answer (score 2):

Any airborn troops (dragons or minions) or use archers and wizards to shot them down. The positive of uses dragons or minions is balloons cannot damage them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, draw them all out then use lightning spells to take them out. They will eliminate the pesky balloons and lower the health of the buildings around them, making them easier to take off. Try to lure the balloons to frustrating defensive buildings for even better result. Always keep two if you can just in case the first lightning spell fails.

Using minions will also help (and be less expensive) since the bombs can't harm them and they can attack air troops like the balloon. Poison spells will also work but will take a while to kill them off.