# How to attack defending dragons

Tags: clash-of-clans

When attacking a base and a dragon comes out of the clan castle what can you do? I followed the steps to [this similar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194843/how-to-attack-defending-balloons) question but it doesn't seem to work. Even with archers and 2 spells the dragon fried them. A lot of the archers weren't even shooting at the dragon, they were shooting at the closest building. How can you prevent this? It's kind of a catch because the dragon only comes out once the buildings are under attack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dragons should be drawn out and surrounded by units that can attack air like wizards, archers, minions or dragons. If you lure them out, they are generally quite easy to defeat with minimal casualties. The real problem is if the clan castle is centralized, making it very difficult to lure out without committing a number of troops. If that happens, heal/rage spells work quite well at preventing losses and quickly defeating the distraction.

EDIT:
Drawing out clan castle troops is done by placing troops in range of the clan castle, causing the  CC troops to come out of the castle. Afterwards, you place just one archer far away from any defenses, such as a builders hut in the corner. Once the dragon gets to the archer, surround the dragon with wizards, minions, etc. and they will quickly defeat it with only a few casualties.

Comment: How do you draw them out?

Comment: @Celeritas, place a troop in the clan castle's sight radius.

Comment: but then they just continue attacking the building

Comment: @Celeritas: You should let that troop die once the dragon has left the castle and place another troop near the edge of the village in order to draw it away from any defenses. Then the dragon will be very vulnerable and easy to overwhelm.

Comment: If you dont have dragons, use archers as bait one bye one. Once it comes out drop another arher a little farther away. But if you are attacking with 10 dragons you can safely ignore castle troops what ever it may be.

Comment: that's what I did wrong, I need to use archers 1 by 1 to draw the dragon out far enough to actually attack it, then make a circle of archers around the dragon

Comment: Note: The dragon have a special taste for barbarians for some reason. They absolutely love them and will attack barbarians if you keep on feeding it some.

Answer (score 1):

This strategy posted by user MizzouDude in Reddit - /r/ClashOfClans, ["[Strategy] How to Kill Clan Castle Dragons Easily"](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClashOfClans/comments/23ysad/strategy_how_to_kill_clan_castle_dragons_easily/), works great in killing a defending CC dragon while minimizing lost troops:

> If done right, you could kill a clan castle dragon by sparing only one
>   or two barbarians/goblins...
>
> First you are going to want to lure out the dragon as you would any
>   other troop. Once out of the range of defenses, start to make a half
>   circle of archers. About half way into making this half circle, drop a
>   troop that will run past the dragon to the base behind it. This will
>   distract the dragon and it will spin around to try and kill that
>   single troop rather than focusing on the group of archers shooting it.
>
> This should kill the dragon quickly without too many lost troops!